# Was it ever explained how Starscream could return as a Transformer ghost?

Tags: transformers

From the original *Transformers* G1 cartoons, how did Starscream return as a ghost? as far as I know Starscream was the only case where a Transformer returned as a ghost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this was ever explained in G1 but it was kind of explained in Beast Wars. From [Transformers wikia](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/Spark#Starscream):

> As established in the Beast Wars episodes "Possession" and "Bad Spark", Starscream possesses a "mutant" immortal spark. Even when his body is destroyed, his spark is not extinguished. This explanation retcons the appearance of Starscream's ghost in some season three episodes from the G1 cartoon; the "ghost" was in fact Starscream's disembodied spark.

Also, from [tfwiki.net](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Starscream_(G1)):

> Starscream's never give up attitude extends even to the afterlife: unlike most Transformers, he has a mutant, indestructible Spark. His life-force cannot be destroyed and can persist even without a body to contain it. However, there is no indication that Starscream (or anybody else) was aware of this fact prior to his destruction.

In summary, it seems he has a mutant spark, probably because of his "never give up attitude" (or possibly vice versa: his mutant spark *caused* that attitude).